# How to get customvalidator to show error in validation summary?

Tags: asp.net

How do I get my customvalidator for my checkbox cbTermsandcond to display in my validationsummary?

At the moment, the error message is displaying next to the checkbox that's being validated.

```
<div class="mainbookingcheckboxleft">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTermsandcond" runat="server" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="You must agree with our Terms and Conditions" 
            onservervalidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate">
    </asp:CustomValidator>

    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
        ShowMessageBox="true"  ShowSummary="False" />
</div>
```

Note, my RequiredFieldValidator controls on my webpage are displaying in the Validation summary as a popup box correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [elegant way to make customvalidator work with validationsummary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811734/elegant-way-to-make-customvalidator-work-with-validationsummary-messagebox)

Comment: That duplicate answer is 3 years old, and part of the script is now redundant.  I need a fresh new answer.